# Understanding the each jquery function - Unexpected output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to wrap my head around the `each` function. In this fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dr1tay6f/2/) 
I would like to iterate through the selected elements of the list box one by one.

Essentially I was expecting an output like this

```
found itemA
found itemB
```

However I get an output like this

```
found itemA,itemB
```

I would like to know why that is happening and how I can fix it. 
This is the code I am using

HTML

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="5" id="test">
    <option>itemA</option>
    <option>itemB</option>
</select>
<br>
<button type="button" id="bid">test</button>
```

JQuery

```
$( "#bid" ).click(function() {
   $("#test").each(function () {
       console.log("found " + $(this).val());
   });           
});
```

Comment: Then I get` found 
                  
                            itemA
                            itemB` The output is still not what I expected it to be

Comment: Well, what do you expect `$(this).val()` to return? And why would `$("#test")` select multiple elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating over the `select` and not the `option`s. The function you passed to each is getting called just once. Change your selector to `#test > option` and, like the comments on the question, change `val()` to `text()`.

```
$( "#bid" ).click(function() {
   $("#test > option").each(function () {
       console.log("found " + $(this).text());
   });           
});
```

Comment: val is for values of form elements, it seems you're trying to get the text of an option.

Answer (score 2):

- You have to specify the elements selector. Using only `#test` won't iterate over `options` because you didn't actually refer to it.

```js
$("#bid").click(function() {
  $("#test option").each(function() {
    console.log("found " + $(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple" size="5" id="test">
  <option>itemA</option>
  <option>itemB</option>
</select>
<br>
<button type="button" id="bid">test</button>
```

Comment: `innerHTML`? Just get `this.value`.

Comment: @Bergi Huh, I was convinced that when there's no `value` property in the `option`, `.val()` won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use

```
$.each($("#test").prop("options"), function () {
    console.log("found " + this.value);
});
```

or

```
$("#test").children().each(function () {
    console.log("found " + this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that might explain it more: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/dr1tay6f/6/

**HTML**

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="5" id="test">
  <option value="a">Item A</option>
  <option value="b">Item B</option>
</select>
<br>
<button type="button" id="bid">test</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $("#bid").click(function() {
    $("#test option").each(function(ind, el) {
      console.log("At Index " + ind +" found Option with Value: " + $(el).val() + " and Label of: " + $(el).html());
    });
  });
});
```

The `$(selector).each(callback(index, element));` will iterate over each element in the selector, passing it's index and element to the function.